# 64-bit ROP-based Buffer Overflow Attack

Tags: buffer-overflow, c, ctf, rop

I am facing a CTF challenge in which I have to conduct an attack using a ROP chain on this program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

// IGNORE
void setup() {
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    setbuf(stderr, NULL);
}
// END IGNORE


void read_file(char* file, char* buffer) {
    int fd = open(file, O_RDONLY);
    read(fd, buffer, 0x200);
}

void main() {
    setup();

    char buffer[0x200];

    puts("can you read flag.txt");

    read_file("./flag.txt", buffer);

    gets(buffer);

    // puts(buffer);
}
```

My plan is to use ROP gadgets to call the read_file function again, and then to call the puts() function to print out the contents of the file. However, while I have the address in memory of the "./flag.txt" string to submit as the first parameter, I don't know what address to use for the second parameter(for char* buffer), or if it is even possible to do this.

Is my strategy even viable to begin with? Should I instead try to use ROP gadgets to call the base library functions(read, open, etc) instead? If my strategy is viable what address/space should I submit as the second parameter? Thanks.

For reference, this is the payload I tried submitting, but for which I got nothing:

```
payload = b"A" * 0x200
payload += b"B" * 0x8
payload += pop_rsi_pop_r15_ret_address + p64(0x7fffffffd950) + p64(flag_txt_string_address) + read_file_address
payload += pop_rdi_ret_address + p64(0x7fffffffd950) + plt_puts_address
```

Also, ASLR is enabled, but PIE is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can read data into the [`.bss` section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.bss) of the program memory. It's readable and writable, and its position and size is defined by the executable itself, so having PIE disabled means it'll have a constant address.

Note that other data may also be stored in the `.bss` section, so you may need to add an offset when reading/writing your own data.